# Get all files from formData

Tags: javascript, php

I have editor where i can upload my images, so everytime when I want to upload image, is creating input file with class "image_add_editor". I add all files in formData, send it in my PHP backend and it returns that I sent only 1 file, but when I check my JS code, it returns that I sent 2 files. Why?

```js
const formData = new FormData()

        const input = document.querySelectorAll(".image_add_editor");
        input.forEach((a) => {
            formData.append("image", a.files[0])
        })

        console.log(formData.getAll("image").length)  // returns 2

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        };
        const req = '/backend/upload.php';
        fetch(req, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            });
```

```html
<?
$count = count($_FILES['image']['name']);

echo $count; // returns 1
```

Comment: For file uploading, you need Content-type `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: You seem to be sending all the files with the same parameter name "image". It's unlikely that PHP can tell the difference, so it just looks like one parameter